# Uploading a CSV file and display preview in datagrid

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, struts2

I want to upload a csv file asynchronously to backend and display the preview data in same page without refreshing/reloading the page. So I want to do it using AJAX.

I am wondering how can we do this using Ajax and Jquery. I am using struts2. Is there any plug-ins available for struts2?

Any help on this regard is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out [Struts2-jQuery-Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/). then simply do this:

```
<s:form action="process-csv">
    <s:file name="fileName"/>
    <sj:submit targets="csvDiv"/>
</s:form>
<sj:div id="csvDiv"/>
```

in your Action `process-csv`, you should read the uploaded file, and output it, then it will show in the div with `id="csvDiv"`.

please try this out, if you got further questions, post again.

**UPDATE**
Form:

```
<s:form action="process-csv">
    <s:file name="fileName"/>
    <sj:submit targets="csvDiv"/>
</s:form>
<sj:div id="csvDiv"/>
```

Action Class:

```
public class ProcessCsv {
    private File fileName;//getter + setter
    private String content;// getter + setter
    public String execute(){
        content = parseCsv(fileName);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

You can use library like [OpenCsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to implement `parseCsv()`
on your `test.jsp`, you only need this:

```
<textarea><s:property value="%{content}"/></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info. I will try this update you as early as possible. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Jaiwo99, I tried to do it, by my page is refreshing when I click on submit button, and I am not sure how can I preview the imported csv data in page. Can you point me to a example? Thanks

Comment: Hi, it is very straight forward, if you click on the `submit` button, it shouldn't refresh the whole page, but the div `csvDiv`

Comment: Hi, Now I am able to upload the file to server without refreshing the page. I forgot to include <sj: head /> tag. After successful uploading of file I am returning the csv data in json format. But not sure how to render it as a table in div csvDiv. If I am placing the below code in action action config the div is not loading with csv data

Comment: the easiest way to do this: put your file in a string, using stream output, then display this string in your page...

Comment: <result type="json">
    <param name="root">
     csvDataList
    </param>
    <param name="wrapPrefix"><![CDATA[<html><body><textarea>]]></param>
    <param name="wrapSuffix"><![CDATA[</textarea></body></html>]]></param>
     </result>

instead of that If I place something like this <result type="success">test.jsp</result>. the div is loading with test.jsp. Could you please let me know how can I load this div with json data as a table.